# wpa_supplicant error RX ctrl_iface - hexdump_ascii(len=11)

Tags: android, android-logcat

I have relatively new Sony Xperia U that I am using to test an app.

Every second when phone and WiFi are active, I get the following error in LogCat:

```
03-15 11:29:36.637: E/wpa_supplicant(6663): RX ctrl_iface - hexdump_ascii(len=11):
03-15 11:29:36.637: E/wpa_supplicant(6663):      53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c                  SIGNAL_POLL     
03-15 11:29:36.637: D/wpa_supplicant(6663): Command received: SIGNAL_POLL
03-15 11:29:36.637: D/wpa_supplicant(6663): nl80211: survey data missing!
```

I have read that it is something to do with WiFi. Well, if I turn WiFi off it does stop.

Does anyone know what this is and how to stop it?